# Register font family in OpTeX

Tags: fonts, minionpro, optex

I was trying to register the `Minion Pro` font family in `OpTeX`, for which I was guided by what was established for the `EB Garamond` font family, but I have not been successful. When doing so just create the file `f-minionpro.opm` similar to `f-ebgaramond.opm` (Change everything related to `Garamond` to `Minion Pro`, including the corresponding math font):

```
%% This is part of the OpTeX project, see http://petr.olsak.net/optex

\_famdecl [Minion Pro] \MinionPro {Based on Minion Pro}
    {\medium \semibold \caps \swash} {\rm \bf \it \bi} {minion-math}
    {[MinionPro-Regular]}
    {\_def\_fontnamegen {[MinionPro-\_currV]:\_capsV\_swaV\_fontfeatures}}

\_wlog{\_detokenize{%
Modifiers:^^J
 \caps ...... caps & small caps^^J
 \swash ..... alternative capitals for \it, \bi^^J
 \medium .... medium weight^^J
 \semibold .. semibold weight (only \bf, \bi are changed)^^J
}}

\_moddef \resetmod {\_fsetV caps={},swa={} \_fvars Regular Bold It BoldIt }
\_moddef \medium   {\_fvars Regular Medium It MediumIt }
\_moddef \semibold {\_fvars Regular SemiBold It SemiBoldIt }
\_moddef \caps     {\_fsetV caps=+smcp;\_ffonum; }
\_moddef \nocaps   {\_fsetV caps={} }
\_moddef \swash    {\_fsetV swa=+swsh; }
\_moddef \noswash  {\_fsetV swa={} }



\_initfontfamily % new font family must be initialized

\_loadmath {[minion-math]}

\_endcode

See the file `f-heros.opm` for information about principles of such
font-macro-files.
```

The `f-minionpro.opm` file was placed in `./tex/optex/base` and the fonts in `./fonts/opentype/public`. Additionally, I entered the `Minion Pro` data to `fams-ini.opm` following what was written for `EB Garamond`.

Doing

```
\fontfam[MinionPro]
```

`OpTeX` does not recognize the font, showing me the list of fonts that it does recognize. I guess I need to do some kind of update to get `Minion Pro` to be recognized by `OpTeX`. I also suspect that I must be missing something when making the `.opm` files. What is missing?

PD: When I placed `f-minionpro.opm` inside the project folder, the font was recognized but not found, even when the fonts were also inside the project folder.

PD: For the `Minion Pro` font, the same variants of the `EB Garamond` font were used (Medium, MediumIt, Semibold and SemiboldIt)

Comment: Tricky for me to test since Minion is a paid font, but the first step is to make sure that `luaotfload` is able to find the font. What do you get when you run `luaotfload-tool --find="Minion Pro"`? You should get something like `resolve : Font "Minion Pro" found! [...] Resolved file name "some/path/minionpro-regular.otf"`. If you get `Cannot find "Minion Pro" in index`, then that means that `luaotfload` (and by extension OpTeX) can't find the font files themselves.

Comment: I get: `Font "Minion Pro" not found`

Comment: Try running `mktexlsr --verbose` followed by `luaotfload-tool --force --update -vvv` (both as root if possible), then run `luaotfload-tool --fuzzy --find="*Minion*"`. Does it find the files then?

Comment: Again `Font "*Minion*" not found`.

Comment: Hmm, so the fonts are either incorrectly named or in an incorrect location. What do you get when you run `kpsewhich minion-regular.otf`? (replace `minion-regular.otf` with whatever the proper filename actually is)

Comment: Well, with `kpsewhich MinionPro-regular.otf` I get nothing

Comment: where should it be located? I put it in `./fonts/opentype/public`, I have seen that there is a Adobe font in `./fonts/opentype/adobe`, `source pro`

Comment: As long as it's somewhere in your TEXMF trees, it shouldn't _really_ matter where you put the files, but I'd recommend putting them in one of the locations listed by `kpsewhich --expand-braces='{$TEXMFHOME,$TEXMFLOCAL}/fonts/opentype/adobe/minion/'`. Make sure to run `mktexlsr` again after putting the files there.

Comment: Looks like only a `mktexlsr` was needed. Indeed, now I have another problem with `\caps`, but I guess I should open another question for that. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Resolved in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709342/register-font-family-in-optex#comment1764143_709342):

> Looks like only a `mktexlsr` was needed. [...] – [juanuni](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14423/juanuni)